# Uninitialized to Boolean C++

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

I am constructing a template structure and I need some trick to do the following:

I have a singly and two dimensional linked list, and I need first construct every node with no data in them after that I have to fill them with the data from a file. So I need `if(x == UNINITIALIZED OR NOT)` since the data could be string, int and double. I couldn't find a common null initializer just for that if check. I hope there is a way to do this.

I tried `if(x == NULL)`, `if(x == 0)`, `if(x == "")`, `if(x == void)`. None of them worked.

Comment: C++ has a static type system. *You* have to decide which type you want.

Comment: Are you using a `union`?  or `void*`?
-EDIT
NM, templated...  Just need to read.

Answer (score 0):

if your node represents one of the types specified, you could simply use a template, template specialization, or overloading.

Comment: One of my friends suggested that keep a bool variable in the node that will check if that node has a data in it named 'occupied'. I guess it will work fine.

Comment: Depending on how your node's data is stored (ie a `union`) a secondary boolean variable indication initialization state would be required.

Comment: @MertToka that would be one approach, particularly if the value at construction is also a valid input value.

Comment: @Justin my friend's suggestion worked fine and it is easy. My nodes and initialization is just suitable for the solution. I just wrote if(x != occupied){occupied=true; ptr->info=info;}.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have those three types, you could create specialized initializer functions for the known types.

```
template <class T>
class CNode {
public:
    CNode() {
       Init(m_Value);
    }

private:
    T m_Value;

    static void Init(T n) { n = 0; }  // Default catch for types that can be set to 0/NULL
    static void Init(bool b) { b = false; }
    static void Init(string str) { str = ""; }
};
```

Of course there are also ways of specifying type specifics for templated functions, but I don't remember that offhand.  I know Boost uses those, it would be a way of specifying additional methods of initialization outside of the original definition.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, I think the following code shows possible and interesting solution which uses two [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries: [Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/index.html) and [Tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple/index.html):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::tuple<std::string, double, int> value_t;
    typedef boost::optional<value_t> node_t;

    std::list<node_t> nodes;

    // first construct every node with no data in them 
    std::fill_n(std::inserter(nodes, nodes.begin()), 5, node_t());

    // check all nodes have not been initialized yet, so they are in "null" state
    auto it = nodes.cbegin();
    while (it != nodes.cend())
    {
        assert(!it->is_initialized());
        ++it;
    }

    // add non-null initialized node
    // or fill with the data from a file, etc.
    node_t n("abc");
    nodes.insert(it, n); 
    assert(nodes.back().is_initialized());
}
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea about the boost. Where do I find it? It may be helpful some time in future. Your solution is a bit complex yet useful. So thank you very much.

Comment: @MertToka I've updated my answer and added links to Boost libraries